# Domain=com.google.GCKFramework.GCKApplicationSessionError Code=1 "failed to start application (com.google.GCKFramework.GCKApplicationSessionError)"

Tags: ios, google-cast

I'm trying to run the Chromecast [iOS sample app](http://github.com/googlecast/cast-ios-sample), using a [whitelisted](https://developers.google.com/cast/whitelisting#whitelist-receiver) Chromecast.

- The official Netflix app on the phone has no trouble sending movies to the Chromecast.
- The movies in the sample app play locally (that is, on the phone or in the iOS simulator).
- I've edited the sample app to use the App ID from the whitelist confirmation email, and also the URL that I told the whitelist crew.
- I verified that that URL retrieves the correct sample javascript.
- I verified that the serial number I told them matches the one on the box, and the receipt.
- The iOS app can see the Chromecast, and retrieves its IP address. In Chrome on the Mac, I can open <IP address>:9222 and see the Chromecast's debug console.
- I've used the Mac Chromecast app to tell the Chromecast to send its serial number to Google when checking for updates, and I've restarted the Chromecast multiple times (and just left it running all day) in case needs to be on to fetch an update.

But, when I actually select a movie in the sample app, I get this error message on the Xcode console:

**GCK Session failed to start: Error Domain=com.google.GCKFramework.GCKApplicationSessionError Code=1 "failed to start application (com.google.GCKFramework.GCKApplicationSessionError)"**

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I received an email this morning from the Chromecast developer support team with corrected application IDs.

I installed the new application ID in the iOS app, and in the javascript, and now the demo app works beautifully.